# ¿Cuándo se usa "considerándole" y "considerándosele"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, conjunciones

Estoy escribiendo un texto y generalmente me gusta hacerlo de forma impersonal. Hay una oración en la que necesito resaltar la percepción colectiva que un objeto tiene respecto a otros de su clase, aquí doy un ejemplo:

(...) Por lo que generalmente se concluye que el tulwar era el más indicado para un combate sin protección, **considerándole/considerándosele** el arma blanca por excelencia de la India del siglo XVI.

He visto el empleo de ambas palabras en otros textos. Sin embargo, no logro entender cuáles son sus reglas de uso.

Comment: Bajo mi punto de vista, suena más impersonal la opción "considerándosele".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma **considerándole** no es impersonal. Podemos comprobarlo al ver que tiene un sujeto implícito, que bien puede ser "yo", "tú", "él/ella", o un sujeto colectivo ("la empresa", "el colegio", "el pueblo", etc.).

Por su parte, la forma **considerándosele** es impersonal, en todos los casos.